# IIS and Certificates, secure a website accessed locally only with just a netBOIS name

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate, iis-6, certificate-authority

Is there anyway to have a local website - not accessed from the outside world - use a certificate from a CA and be accessed with a netBIOS name rather than the FQDN?

So if that's not worded correctly, I have a copy of the built in WebServer cert, and want my SharePoint website to use it with just the local server name. I get certificate errors accessing https://SharePoint01, but no errors when accessing https://SharePoint01.test.local

I have total admin rights so the certificate can be amended at Certificate Authority level, or during the install onto my SharePoint machine.
I assume I need to change the DNS or Subject Alternative Name at the point of Certificate Enrollment? But whatever I try either doesn't work, or not allowed.

Right now I have the Subject as:

```
    DC = SharePoint01
    DC = Test
    DC = Local
```

And the SAN as:

`DNS Name=SharePoint01.Test.Local`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ask whoever gave you that certificate to add a DNS Name field for SharePoint01 to it.

Comment: @LexLi - Thank you for the comment.
I made it. Certificates are not at the forefront of my skillset! I assume you mean during the enrolment stage? I get "no permitted name constraint for <DNS Name=SharePoint01>" error if I try to add or change the DNSName value

Comment: Good. Then you know how web browsers verify the URL against the server certificate :) and a lot easier to troubleshoot such issues in the future.

Comment: No I mean, I made the certificate. Obviously I've not made it right but don't know at what point. On the CA? Or when enrolling it. I can't seem to enrole it with just the netBIOS name, it's giving me all kinds of errors. Is this because of a setting at CA level?

Comment: 1) I will suggest you use self-signed certificates to test things out first https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/self-signed.html#self-signed-certificate-wizard With enough success and knowledge it is a lot easier to move on 2) When in doubt, you can always run diagnostics to learn what's missing https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html

Comment: Sadly that's the problem. We have to move on from using self-signed to CA signed. I'm not doing this for fun. We don't have any certificate specialists, instead I'm being asked as the guy who installed SharePoint to get it working using a CA Template. I've built the template,  I don't know if I'm missing a flag or what-not, and it works fine if I enter the FQDN in my browser, I'm just out to know what setting needs addressing to get it working using the netBIOS.

Comment: It goes beyond programming, so I personal think it is off topic from here. But you can always find guides over the internet on how to properly configure the template to support multiple DNS names, such as https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/931351/how-to-add-a-subject-alternative-name-to-a-secure-ldap-certificate About why "no permitted name constraint" happens, again ask the search engine.